# Restrict AWS S3 bucket with specific domain

Tags: php, laravel, security, amazon-s3, video

I am getting trouble with writing s3 bucket policy. I want to make my s3 bucket only available only for my domain. So basically

if a user is  requested

from **[www.otherwebsite.com](http://www.otherwebsite.com)**
the s3 file shouldn't appear.

but if a user is requested from mywebiste.com
from **[www.mywebiste.com](http://www.mywebiste.com)**
the s3 file should appear.

I've also tried the HTTP referral way which AWS mentioned (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4)
but it doesn't work either and still getting issue. So my website content (video) can still access from the s3 URL link which is making security issue.

solution snippet for s3 bucket policy rule

I've tried to add this policy.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "HTTP referer policy example",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Allow GET requests originating from www.creativecodermm.com and creativecodermm.com.",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::creativecoder/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:Referer": [
                    "https://www.creativecodermm.com/*",
                    "https://creativecodermm.com/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: **Note:** Using `referer` to restrict access is **very poor security** because it is _very_ easy to fake. Do not attempt to protect any confidential or private information using this method.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work either and still getting issue"? Please edit your Question and show us the policy you used, and tell us how you tried to access the content and exactly what happened.

Comment: Your site appears to be using CloudFront? Please provide an example URL to a file (eg an image) in your `creativecoder` S3 bucket that should be blocked by the above policy, but is permitting access.